# pandastable goes off the frame

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am kinda stuck why my table goes off the frame while I have activated scrollbar in pandastable. Only half of the columns is shown in the subframe!

```
subframe = LabelFrame(tab1,text="Measurements",  width=350, height=490)
subframe.grid(row=0, column=2)

df=pd.DataFrame(df_pred)

frame = tk.Frame(subframe)
frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

pt = Table(frame, dataframe=df,showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)

pt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

try it -
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)